# Where to download php 7.3 for mamp

Tags: php, mamp

I can't seem to find the website for downloading php 7.3 for mamp (mac os). Could you advise me where I can download it? (I don't use mamp pro)

Comment: There isn't a specific version for use with MAMP. The PHP downloads may be found [here](https://www.php.net/downloads.php).